# Laravel Search Array of Values

Tags: laravel

In my user registration workflow, I ask the user to select a pre-defined list of classifications (which I use a series of checkboxes for). Currently, I update my model with those values (or a blank value if the box isn't checked) when they move to the next step. These are not currently structured as an array, rather as a separate and distinct checkbox.

My 2 questions are as follows:

1) I read that if I save the checkboxes as an array I won't be able to easily search the database for users with a particular classification.

2) If that's true, I'm fine with my current structure, but I need to properly validate (server-side) that at least one of the checkboxes is selected otherwise provide an error. I have tried the following, but it doesn't return anything and the database record is created with nothing in each column.

```
if ($request->all() === "")
{
    return Request::json('you must select one');
}
```

Database Table Migration:

```
Schema::create('user_type', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->string('games');
    $table->string('art');
    $table->string('music');
    $table->string('building_stuff');
    $table->string('educational');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Javascript: (I submit as AJAX)

```
$('.modal-type-btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($('.checkbox-games').is(':checked'))
    {
        var games = "games";
    } else {
        var games = "";
    }

    if($('.checkbox-art').is(':checked'))
    {
        var art = "art";
    } else {
        var art = "";
    }

    if($('.checkbox-music').is(':checked'))
    {
        var music = music;
    } else {
        var music = "";
    }

    if($('.checkbox-building-stuff').is(':checked'))
    {
        var buildingStuff = "buildingstuff";
    } else {
        var buildingStuff = "";
    }

    if($('.checkbox-educational').is(':checked'))
    {
        var educational = "educational";
    } else {
        var educational = "";
    }       

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/profile/setup/1",
        data: {games:games, art:art, music:music, buildingStuff:buildingStuff, educational:educational},
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, firstly you're much better of using them as an array and doing something like:

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[games]" value="1" />
```

that way, you can just get the form data and pass that into your `$.ajax` call:

```
...
data: $('form').serialize(),
....
```

and then in your controller, checking that the length of `options` is at least one:

```
$options = Input::get('options');
if(count($options) > 0){ ... }
```

You'll also probably want to define a list of "allowed" options and then use that to build your query:

```
private $_allowed_options = array('education', 'buildingStuff' ...);

public function update()
{
  $options = Input::get('options');
  foreach($this->_allowed_options as $allowed_options){
    if(array_key_exists($allowed_option, $option)){
      // add this option to our sql to add it to our user
      // as they have selected it
    }else{
      // the user didn't select this one, so add it to be removed
      // from the users 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So, someone's comment that it's more difficult to search if stored as an array sounds incorrect.

Comment: If you're using Eloquent and a Many to Many relationship you should be able to use `sync` with only the allowed items which does the removal for you. unless you tell it _not_ to using the second parameter [See: BelongsToMany.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L737)